# Contact Page error 404

Tags: magento2, contact-us

I have installed Magento 2.3 and then installed custom paid theme.After this when i open my contact page the page shows 404 error. i have check the controller URL and other things to debug but i don't found any solution.

so my question is , do i need to create a CMS page for contact?
I have enabled the page from Back-end but still 404 Error. 
I disabled all the module and changed the theme to Luma but still 404 error.

> http://prntscr.com/nw35ty

Any one tell me how i can debug this?

Comment: Is the order page like Customer login,registaion page is  opening?

Comment: Yes all the other pages are opening.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a CMS page for the contact us page.

If you do and it shares the same url key that could be what's causing problem.  In which case delete any CMS page with 'contact' url key.

Have you tried different URL options

https://domain.com/contact/

https://domain.com/contact

https://domain.com/index.php/contact/

https://domain.com/index.php/contact

Maybe try http:// too for all of the above.  Just rule out some weird routing issue.

Comment: Yes. By using this www.abc.com/index.php/contact is working. How i can set this to normal url?

Comment: So that means controller and layout XML is good. Check url rewrites is on https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/url-rewrite-configuration.html , alsp check rewrites themselves https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/url-rewrite-create.html you are looking for anything that has contact as request path and doesn't look right

Comment: followed the above links but none of the are useful for me.

Comment: In admin, Marketing > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites. Look for any request path that says `/contact/` or similar.

Comment: there is no path having Contact or similar